# Embedded Google Map: stop the callout from automatically appearing?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[image]

Is there any way to stop the callout from automatically appearing on an embedded google map? I know the user can click to dismiss it and all that, but the way my map is set up, the callout virtually always sticks out of the frame, and apart from looking really bad, the name is cut off rendering it completely useless. Is there any URL parameter or something i can pass to the iFrame to stop it appearing>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a iwloc-parameter which defines where to show a infowindow.

I don't know if it's documented somewhere, but it seems to work like this:

- When the iwloc-parameter is missing, a infowindow is shown for the first marker(place), it's the A-marker when available
- When the iwloc-parameter is present and set to a value from A-J, a infowindow is shown for the marker(place) with the index supplied via the iwloc-parameter when the marker(place) exists.

So what to do: append a iwloc-parameter to the iframe-src with a value different from A-J , e.g.:

```
&amp;iwloc=false
```